# How to generate a path with id for a newly created method in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes

I'm adding new method 'editpass' to existing REST based User controller.

I want to pass the id to the editpass method which edit does for the edit_user_path

i have added the following in routes.rb

```
resources :user do
    collection do
     get 'editpass'
    end
 end
```

and

```
 match 'user/:id/editpass' => 'user#editpass'
```

rake:routes produces following for the editpass :

```
 /user/:id/editpass(.:format)    {:action=>"editpass", :controller=>"user"
```

this routes doesn't have a path name.

what is the bestway to generate path for the method with id in rails3

Thanks in advance

Senling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 match 'user/:id/editpass' => 'user#editpass', :as => 'user_editpass'
```

That should make user_editpass_path(:id => @user) work.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should pluralize `user` to `users` to be more conventional if you're using `resources` and not `resource`

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :editpass
  end
end
```

Then you can use:

```
link_to "Edit Pass", [:editpass, :users]
```

or

```
link_to "Edit Pass", editpass_users_path
```

Also using `match 'user/:id/editpass' => 'user#editpass'` is messing your routes and it is absolutley stupid idea, because your match is actually a `member`, while you've added it as a `collection`